# Weird sequence involving WSAECONNABORTED

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-9, swi-prolog

I'm investigating a strange sequence of events for IE9 talking to the SWI-Prolog HTTP server.  After clearing the browser cache and loading /, I see this happening.

- IE9: GET /
- Prolog replies with a redirection to /home
- IE9: GET /home
- Prolog replies with the main page (HTML, referring to 7 images, css, js)
- IE9 opens 7 connections for these
- It *seems* that Windows closes all these using WSAECONNABORTED.  The
  server reports this error on some of the connections for reading the
  request and some for sending the reply.  IE9 developers interfacse says
  *aborted* on all.
- IE9 opens 4 connections, which work fine and then 3, which also work fine.

Does anyone has an idea why this all happens and who is initiating the aborts?
The (Prolog) server itself poses no limit on the number of connections (unless
there is a default for WinSock that needs to be changed explicitly).

P.s.  Platform: Win7, 64-bits.

Comment: Can you test the requests with another browser or wget? That might tell you which side is at fault.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I just tried with FF18.0.  Here, we see a request for /home, then 6 concurrent requests for css and js files and then 4 concurrent requests for images.  All finishes nicely.  Switching on low-level debugging at the server reveals no network errors.  Now the question is whether using 6 or 7 concurrent connections is important.  I'll try to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Historically the HTTP protocol had a traditional limit of four connections per client for HTTP/1.0 and of two connections for HTTP/1.1 (under RFC2616 section 8.1). I suspect that your Prolog server is enforcing this limit. Alternatively it may the actions of an intermediate firewall, which nowadays do all sorts of things so that it is hard to keep track.

As it is it looks like IE is behaving correctly be detecting the limit and falling back to a lower limit.

For interest here is some documentation from the IE6 days:

- http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=183110

Comment: Thanks.  Concerning I wrote most of the SWI-Prolog socket stuff as well as the HTTP server, you can be sure there is no limit on the number of connections there :-)  Yes.  IE9 correctly detects it must lower the number of connections.  I'm mostly worried about stateful HTTP services that are faced with double requests because some of the connections read a valid request and are aborted during the output phase.  There is no firewall; we are talking localhost connections on a vanilla Win7Pro (64) installation in a virtual machine.

Comment: @JanWielemaker, are you using the kernel-mode HTTP driver HTTP.sys to handle incoming requests? I.e. are you using HttpListener or simlar. If so that's who is doing it.

Comment: Or third-party firewall SW?

Comment: None of all.  The Prolog HTTP server is written in Prolog and is based on TCP sockets, which are ultimately implemented using WinSock.  Except for Prolog and FF18, there is nothing installed on the system.

Comment: I assume you have already tried F12 developer tools network monitoring? IE9 is not doing OPTIONS or anything, right? Also are you running under `inetd` or are you running a standalone server?

Comment: I used IE9 devtools.  IE9 claims _aborted_ for the failing queries, both if the server failed to read the query and failed to send the reply.  What do you mean by OPTIONS?  Server is a stand alone app.

Comment: Makes sense.  But, there are two developments.  First of all, the error mysteriously disappeared after a reboot!?  Then, another error led me to a mistake in the low-level socket code that can lead to invalid calls on the socket which, if I understand the docs, could cause this error.  Let us leave it here until the error either reappears or is definitely fixed.  Thanks.